# How do I set EC2 instances with a specific tag to terminate automatically after a set amount of time after launch?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

We use Vagrant to launch and provision instances upon each commit to our codebase, which a continuous deployment server then runs tests against. The continuous deployment server launches the instance before running tests, but it just halts everything if one of the tests fail, and I couldn't find a way that would reliably terminate the instances in these cases.

So instead, what I'd like to do is launch the instances, tag them as temporary, and have them terminated automatically after a preset time.

- The most obvious solution would be to schedule a shutdown when provisioning the box. I am looking for a nicer way to do this though, since we use the same Vagrantfile to provision development virtual machines, which should not shut down by themselves.
- AWS CloudWatch can shut down instances after certain events happen (e.g. CPU idle for 30 minutes), but I couldn't find a way to apply a rule to all new instances (let alone to all new instances with a given tag.)
- I also had a look at AWS Auto Scaling, but it wouldn't let me have zero instances active for a launch configuration.

Comment: There is no facility in AWS can do scheduled instances termination. So you need to have your own scheduler to trigger the termination via AWS API. <br/> Also I don't get why you can't stop the instance using your CI/CD server that's a more reasonable place to do this

Answer (score 1):

[An instance can terminate itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541363/self-terminating-aws-ec2-instance) and also [access its own tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883315/query-ec2-tags-from-within-instance). Therefore you just need to figure out how to run that from within the instance after a certain period of time if the instance has a particular tag.

You could either use a cron job, or perhaps something like [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to execute the termination if it detects your CI process isn't running for more than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways, best & easiest will be:

1. Configure AWS CLI tool on Windows/Linux EC2 instance
2. Create script that extracts instance-id from meta data available on EC2.
3. You can create shell/bash script that can execute below mentioned command:

**terminate-instances --instance-id i-******* --region ap-southeast-1**

4. And you can trigger this script in case of any error/event is encountered.

I would also suggest you to create AMI of windows/linux ec2 instance with hardcoded AWS CLI configuration & EC2 terminate script. And use this AMI to create new instances.